# Docker removes downloaded files

Tags: download, docker, boot2docker

I'm trying to set up a Docker container for testing a Magento extension. I would expect to do that with a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM php:5.4-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html
ADD http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.0.1/magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz /var/www/html
# Other installation steps
```

But that fails:

```
2014/09/27 17:03:25 lchown /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/d5ced8f20d760458093f2993ea25ffa9a644c93d5b134e793f820f53dfc2d70d/var/www/html/tmp: not a directory
```

I gather it has something to do with me using boot2docker on OS X. (I recall from a while back that OS X has some filesystem sharing problems with Docker.) So I tried again with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.4-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html
# We should be able to use ADD to fetch a remote file, but
# something is causing that to fail (OS X Docker limitations, I guess?)
RUN ["/usr/bin/curl", "-O", "http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.0.1/magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz"]
RUN ["/bin/tar", "-xzf", "magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz"]
# Other installation steps
```

When I run the above, curl executes just fine and exits without error, but the resultant container does not contain the downloaded file, so the downstream tar command fails.

```
Step 2 : RUN ["/usr/bin/curl", "-O", "http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.0.1/magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz"]
 ---> Running in 2695c5e95f77
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 21.9M  100 21.9M    0     0   817k      0  0:00:27  0:00:27 --:--:--  842k
 ---> bb716a60c4ef
Removing intermediate container 2695c5e95f77
Step 3 : RUN ["/bin/tar", "-xzf", "magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz"]
 ---> Running in 95cc533947c1
tar (child): magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
/bin/tar: Child returned status 2
/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
2014/09/27 17:07:47 The command [/bin/tar -xzf magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz] returned a non-zero code: 2
```

If I inspect the intermediate container, the file is indeed not there.

```
$ docker run bb716a60c4ef /bin/sh -c 'pwd && ls -al'
/var/www/html
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 27 21:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root     4096 Sep 23 11:09 ..
```

So where did it go, and how can I set up a Dockerfile that allows me to download and modify the filesystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here to be aware of. I'll start with the first `Dockerfile` as the fix for that one is fairly easy:

```
FROM php:5.4-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html
ADD http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.0.1/magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz /var/www/html/
# Other installation steps
```

Did you catch it? Adding a `/` to the end of the destination tells the `ADD` command to treat it as a folder. See the 3rd bullet point for the copy rules at https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add.

The second `Dockerfile` is a little more of a mystery to me. But I suspect it has something to do with the parent image setting `/var/www/html` as a volume to skip layer versioning. See https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/5.4/apache/Dockerfile#L46.